# vuetify v-data-table using search function to search for item's property that is not indicated in the headers

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

My table looks like this:

[image]

I have a templated 'product name' wherein code goes like this:

```html
                <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
                  <v-list-item two-line>
                    <v-list-item-avatar style="width: 70px; height: 70px" tile>
                      <v-img :src="item.img" alt="John" />
                    </v-list-item-avatar>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                      <v-list-item-title style="">
                        <a
                          style="
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: #0b0b0b;
                            font-size: 0.9em;
                          "
                          >{{ item.name }} {{ item.variation }}</a
                        >
                      </v-list-item-title>
                      <v-list-item-subtitle class="mt-1">
                        <small class="mr-5">
                          <v-icon small>mdi-package-variant</v-icon>
                          {{ item.sku }}
                        </small>
                        <small>
                          {{ item.shop_name }}
                        </small>
                      </v-list-item-subtitle>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </v-list-item>
                </template>
```

as I understand, the search ONLY search for the value from the headers we indicated my headers btw:

```js
      headers: [
        { text: "Product Name", value: "name" },
        { text: "Quantity", value: "quantity" },
        { text: "Price", value: "price" },
        { text: "Orders", value: "itemsSold" },
        { text: "Revenue", value: "revenue" },
        { text: "Status", value: "active" },
      ],
```

How do I search un-declared value from headers? such as MEDIHEAL-MASK-PLACENTAREVITAL-EX (the subtitle for the product name of the first item in the table)

I was thinking of putting another value in the headers without the "text" element and templating the value to display nothing to the table. Any cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this:

1. Have the searchable prop in your items array:

```js
items: [
  // ... 
  { name: "MEDIHEAL Beauty Mask", quantity: 483, price: 0, somePropThatsNotVisible: "String it could be found by"  }
  // ...
]
```

2. Use a custom filter:

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" :search="search" :custom-filter="filter">
```

```js
methods: {
  filter (value, search, item) {      
    return Object.values(item).some(prop => {
      return String(prop).includes(search)
    })
  }
},
```

That's it! now all props are searchable but not shown if not included in the headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the filter property on the header definition for that column.

```
headers: [
  { 
    text: "Product Name", value: "name", filter: product => { 
      // compare product.property against this.search and return true/false
    } 
  },
  // ... your other col definitions
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple solution:

First modify the opening v-data-table tag:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="products"
  :search="search"
  :custom-filter="filter"
>
```

and then in the `<script setup>` add:

```html
<script setup>
  function filter(value, search, item) {
  return String(item.name).toLowerCase().includes(search);
  }
</script>
```

where item.name will point to column desired to be filtered.